# DashDot/Dash style within Windows Forms drawn incorrectly and Panels vs ShapeContainers

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm creating an UI with a panel(`System.Windows.Forms.Panel`) which will contain a Rectangle/Ellipse and the size(width/height) of the shape is dependent on the horizontal and vertical sliders. The code below does achieve to some extent the desired behavior. However, A line representing the centre of the panel with no Style works fine whereas a style of `DashDot` or `Dash` results in lines drawn across the diagonals and sides of the panels instead of the specified points(startPoint, endPoint). Is there a way to centre the rectangle based on the size of the panel?

```
private void vScroll_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    this.vScrollValue.Text = vScrollBar.Value.ToString();
    panel.Invalidate(/*myRectangle*/);
}

private void hScrollBar_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    this.hScrollValue.Text = hScrollBar.Value.ToString();
    panel.Invalidate(/*myRectangle*/);
}

private void panel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    myRectangle = new Rectangle(90, 90, hScrollBar.Value, vScrollBar.Value);
    System.Text.StringBuilder messageBoxCS = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("panel.Location.X = {0} panel.Location.Y = {1} (panel.Size.Height/2) = {2}", panel.Location.X, panel.Location.Y, e.ClipRectangle);
    //MessageBox.Show(messageBoxCS.ToString(), "Panel Paint");
    //Panel's midpoint (location(x,y) = 88,44, Size(x,y) = 182,184)
    Point startPoint = new Point(e.ClipRectangle.Location.X, e.ClipRectangle.Location.Y + (e.ClipRectangle.Size.Height / 2));
    Point endPoint = new Point(e.ClipRectangle.Location.X + e.ClipRectangle.Size.Width,     e.ClipRectangle.Location.Y + (e.ClipRectangle.Size.Height / 2));

    Pen dashRed = Pens.Red;
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, myRectangle);
    //dashRed.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.DashDot;
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, startPoint, endPoint); 
}
```

Within the `InitializeComponent()` method the paintHandler event is registered as follows:

```
 this.panel.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.panel_Paint);
```

Also, being new to C#, Should I be using `Micorsoft.VisualBasic.Powerpack` - ShapeContainers/RectangleShape/EllipseShape instead of using the WinForms.Panel?

Comment: Using PaintEventArgs.ClipRectangle is *not* correct.  It is unpredictable, it tells you what part of the client area needs to be painted.  Which has nothing to do with where you want these lines to appear.  It is not clear where you want them to be.

Comment: I strongly recommend WPF as the default Windows Desktop UI technology. It has much greater support for everything and is really easier to work with, much more so if you need advanced graphics stuff. winforms is a really outdated technology not recommended for any new projects anymore, only to maintain legacy applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be right:

```
private void panel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    myRectangle = new Rectangle(90, 90, hScrollBar.Value, vScrollBar.Value);
    System.Text.StringBuilder messageBoxCS = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("panel.Location.X = {0} panel.Location.Y = {1} (panel.Size.Height/2) = {2}", panel.Location.X, panel.Location.Y, e.ClipRectangle);
    //MessageBox.Show(messageBoxCS.ToString(), "Panel Paint");
    //Panel's midpoint (location(x,y) = 88,44, Size(x,y) = 182,184)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, myRectangle);
    if(e.ClipRectangle.Location.Y < this.Size.Height / 2 && e.ClipRectangle.Location.Y + e.ClipRectangle.Size.Height > this.Size.Height / 2)
    {
    Point startPoint = new Point(e.ClipRectangle.Location.X, this.Size.Height / 2);
    Point endPoint = new Point(e.ClipRectangle.Location.X + e.ClipRectangle.Size.Width,  this.Size.Height / 2);
    Pen dashRed = Pens.Red;
    dashRed.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.DashDot;
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(dashRed, startPoint, endPoint); 
    }  
}
```

This should be how to make it work with ClipRectangle. Or you could ignore them, as Hans noted, probably in this simple app it wouldn't cause any slowdowns.